# Foreign Key constraint is incorrectly formed - Laravel 7

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7

I was trying to set a column to foreignID using a new migration in Laravel 7 but I am encountering a strange error.

I will go step by step with this so that it gets clear for everyone.

Firstly, I created a questions table using the migration below -

```
        Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->longText('body');
            $table->unsignedInteger('views')->default(0);
            $table->unsignedInteger('answers_count')->default(0);
            $table->integer('votes')->default(0);
            $table->integer('best_answer_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

In the above table, user_id is a foreign key which is contained in the users ID in the users table. This works perfectly fine.

Then I created an `Answers` table with the below migration

```
       Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('question_id');
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->longText('body');
            $table->integer('votes_count')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Now what I want is, the column named `best_answer_id` in Questions table, should be a foreign key constrained to the `id` in the Answers table.

To achieve that, I created a new migration called `make_foreign_best_answers_id_in_questions` and the migration is here:

```
        Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('best_answer_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('answers')
                    ->onDelete('SET NULL');
        });
```

According to my knowledge, this should set the `best_answer_id` column to a foreign ID that should reference to the ID in answers table.

On running `php artisan migrate`` it throws a weird error that reads

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel-qa`.`questions` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `questions` add constraint `questions_best_answer_id_foreign` foreign key (`best_answer_id`) references `answers` (`id`) on delete SET NULL)

As a side note, I know references()->on() was changed for Laravel 7 and it now can work with constrained() but the error in both cases remains the same. Please help me solve this thing.

Thanks and Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

`->id()` is `->bigInteger()` not `->integer()`
and it also is unsigned. 
As column types must match to have a foreign key constraint it should be:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('best_answer_id')->nullable();
```

insead of:

```
        $table->integer('best_answer_id')->nullable();
```

Comment: so the ID by default in laravel is bigInteger?

Comment: yes, as you can see in https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations

Comment: @Steal1702 is it the same error?
Also note that I updated my answer a bit

Comment: yes I tried both unsignedBigInteger() and bigInteger()->unsigned() but the error remains the same i.e.  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel-qa`.`questions` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `questions` add constraint `questions_best_answer_id_foreign` foreign key (`best_answer_id`) references `answers` (`id`) on delete SET NULL)

Comment: Yes it did it. When I used $table->foreign('best_answer_id')->references('id') ->on('answers')->onDelete('SET NULL'); I get the above error but when i used constrained() instead of references()->on() I get the error saying  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') on delete SET NULL' at line 1 (SQL: alter table `questions` add constraint `questions_best_answer_id_foreign` foreign key (`best_answer_id`) references `` () on delete SET NULL)

Comment: try using `answer_id` instead of `best_answer_id`

Comment: I think it has to be "best_answer_id" @Alex

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal, run:

```
php artisan make:migration modify_best_answer_id_to_bigint_unsigned_not_null_to_questions_table
--table=questions
```

which created a migration file for you to change the data type of 'best_answer_id'.

In up() method in your migration file, change 'best_answer_id' by using unsignedBigInterger('best_answer_id')->nullable()->change();

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('best_answer_id')->nullable()->change();
    });
}
```

Then, in your terminal, run:

```
php artisan make:migration add_foreign_best_answer_id_to_questions_table --table=questions
```

Then, in this migration file, you add foreign 'best_answer_id' to questions table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('best_answer_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('answers')
              ->onDelete('SET NULL');
    });
}
```

Lastly, run:

```
php artisan migrate
```

It works for me.
Hope it will work for you!